# Formatting an Angular Material Form Field Number to 2 Decimal Places?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

If we have an Angular Material Form Field containing number like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput
    readonly
    type="number"
    formControlName="unitsFulfilled"
    placeholder="Units Fulfilled">
</mat-form-field>
```

How do we format it to 2 decimal places.  Do we need to do it on the number itself before assigning to the control via `formControlName`?

Comment: There is not "out of the box" implementation, because this can be done in multiple ways - imagine situation when someone types 10 into the input.
You can display it as 10,00 but keep the underlying model as 10.
You can bind into some event (say, blur) and change the data then - which will also change the way it's displayed.

Comment: OK - In this case I'm using the form as a "Review" of data, so it looks like the data has to be formatted before it is assigned to the form.

Comment: Got no time for a full answer, but what you want is to write a directive that provides different implementation for MAT_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR injection token. This means that the field will use different getter and setter to interact between the input element and bound value.

Some read up can be found here:
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-material-matinput-control-with-thousands-separation-ebcbb7b027f4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the create a directive and use it in the HTML. Kindly refer the following link for the same.

[Allow only two decimal places](https://stackblitz.com/edit/limit-two-digit-decimal-place)

In an example, there is simple input field. But you can also use it with the material UI components.

Answer (score 2):

In my Angular project I will need make these changes to stackblitz example

```
const next: string = [
      /*  current.slice(0, position), */ current.slice(position),
      event.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' || ',' : event.key,
    ].join('');
```

otherwise I couldn't drive more than two digits before the dot.